# Imacros: Choosing Country in Gmail Account Creation

Tags: gmail, imacros, phone-number, verification, account

I am trying to automate create Gmail Account but the problem is only merely about how I input the phone dial code. I am trying to change default US phone dial, become Indonesian phone pattern (+62) in automate. Any way to do this?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cf8MF.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below code. The first tag will clear the field and the second tag will enter the phone number, so based on the input dial code the flag will be selected automatically

```
TAG XPATH="//*[@id='RecoveryPhoneNumber']" CONTENT=
EVENTS TYPE=KEYPRESS XPATH="//*[@id='RecoveryPhoneNumber']" CHARS="+15334342354"
```

Comment: Hi Jagadeesh, big thanks!
It has been resolved for now. But one more stuff, that after clicking on submit button, it now pop up a TOS agreement, which is couldn't been accepted until I scrolled it down until the end.

As I am pretty new in iMacros scripting, I didn't know any other way to manipulate like this.

Any way to do this?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking about... I tried to complete the form and it didn't displayed any popup to me